# I want to supress the display of group headers in Crystal 2008

Tags: grouping, crystal-reports-2008

I have 3 group headers with counts and it displays:

group1 count
group2 count
group3 count

then I display details (or suppress)
Everything is good.

In my group header "choices"  there is a "none"  so if I only want to group by group1 and select "NONE" for group2 and group3 it now displays:

group1 count
NONE count
NONE count

Details (or not)

But I DO NOT WANT to display the "NONE" with the count.  I don't want to display anything except group1 that I chose.
So I would want it to look like this:
group1 count

details (or not)

If I chose a group1 and 1 group2 but NONE for group3 then I would want it to display:
group1 count
group2 count

details (or not)
Does that make sense?  Been searching but nothing seems to apply.

Thanks!

Comment: how or from where are you selecting `None` in report? by parameters or by manual entry or by anyother means?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional suppress in Section Expert.

In Design view right click on the group and go to Section Expert. Then add a formula: `If (Group #2({XXX...}) = "NONE") THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE`

Hope this helps!!